# How can I get an html table into python if the table has different tabs?

Tags: python, html, parsing

https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries is the website that I'm using and I'm trying to get the table with All tab selected to pull from html into my jupyter notebook. The problem I seem to be having is if I use class = 'table' it pulls all continent tabs first then the all table and it messes up how my data gets pulled in when I try looking at rows.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries'
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.status_code) #Checking the http response status code. Should be 200
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
all_tables=soup.find_all("table")
right_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'table'})
col_headers = [th.getText() for th in right_table.findAll('th')]
data = [[td.getText() for td in right_table.findAll('td')] for tr in right_table()]
```

When I try to combine the col_headers and data it says I have13 columns passed, data had 2990 columns. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "flattened" the table - created a list of all `<td>`s. What you need to do is to create a **nested** list:

```
data = [ [ td.text for td in tr.find_all("td") ] for tr in right_table.find_all("tr")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_header)
print(df.shape) # (231, 13)
```